# Bookmarklet and tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, bookmarklet

function loadBookmarklet() {
  var scriptT = document.createElement("script");
  scriptT.src = "http://abc.com/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js";
  scriptT.type = "text/javascript";

document.body.appendChild(scriptT);
  tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "simple"
        });
  };

i am getting the error tinyMCE is not defined, can anyone please help me with this?

**New Error**

Here is the new code that i have which is giving me  another error

```
function loadBookmarklet() {
      var scriptT = document.createElement("script");
      scriptT.src = "http://abc.com/tiny_mce.js";
          scriptT.type = "text/javascript";
      scriptT.onload = function(){}
      document.body.appendChild(scriptT);
      tinyMCE.init({ mode : "textareas", theme : "simple" }); 
      newTM = tinyMCE;
      var scriptW = document.createElement("script");
      scriptW.src = "http://abc.com/widget.js";
      scriptW.type = "text/javascript";
      document.body.appendChild(scriptW);

    }
```

in my widget.js i am trying to set the textarea in the widget.js to the editor

```
newTM.activeEditor.setContent(selectedText);
```

the error is

newTM.activeEditor is null

Comment: check out the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

thats because you are not waiting for the tiny_mce.js to finish loading before you refer to the `tinyMCE` variable

You need to defer the `tinyMCE.init` code until the file is loaded. there are a couple of ways to do this

1. Attach an `onload / oncomplete` handler to the injected script element, and then move the init code inside that handler. *(This method may vary from browser to browser in terms of `onload` and `oncomplete`)*
2. set up a `setTimeout` function that checks for the existence of `tinyMCE`,
           1. if it does not exist, it calls itself again
           2. if it exists the timeout is cleared and the init script is called

I usually use the second method, so you code can be adjusted to

```
var scriptT = document.createElement("script"); 
scriptT.src = "http://abc.com/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"; scriptT.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(scriptT);

//Your script loading code is above this line

function TM_wait() { //this function checks for existence of tinyMCE
  if(typeof tinyMCE == 'undefined') {
    window.setTimeout(TM_wait,100); 
    //calls itself if tinyMCE is not loaded
  }else{
    tinyMCE.init({ mode : "textareas", theme : "simple" }); 
    //calls the init function cos tinyMCE is loaded
  }

}

TM_wait(); // calls the checker function for the first time
```

---

### EDIT

In response to your edit, try this

```
function loadBookmarklet() {
      var scriptT = document.createElement("script");
      scriptT.src = "http://abc.com/tiny_mce.js";
      scriptT.type = "text/javascript";
      scriptT.onload = function(){
        var scriptW = document.createElement("script");
        scriptW.src = "http://abc.com/widget.js";
        scriptW.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptW.onload = function(){
           newTM = tinyMCE;
           newTM.init({ mode : "textareas", theme : "simple" }); 
        }
        document.body.appendChild(scriptW);
      }
      document.body.appendChild(scriptT);
}
```

step by step of what's happening above:

1. TinyMCE is loaded
2. when tinyMCE is **finished loading**, your widget is loaded
3. when your widget is **finished loading**, the variable `newTM` is created as an alias of `tinyMCE`
4. tinyMCE is initialised

Because we wait for tinyMCE and the widget.js to finish loading, everything is set up properly and in order. Now your `newTM` should contain a reference to tinyMCE

Comment: i added the code that you have mentioned above, though it gives me that the variable is "undefined", it seems to be in some kind of infinite loop. new code is below, am i missing anything??

function TM_wait() { 
  if(typeof tinyMCE == 'undefined') {
    window.setTimeout(TM_wait,100); 
  }else{
    tinyMCE.init({ mode : "textareas", theme : "simple" }); 
  }
}
 function loadBookmarklet() {
  var scriptT = document.createElement("script");
  scriptT.src = "http://abc./jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js";
  scriptT.type = "text/javascript";
  document.body.appendChild(scriptT);
  TM_wait();
}

Comment: it should be in a loop until tinyMCE is loaded.  
Please check if the tiny_mce.js is not doing a 404

Comment: i was able to solve the error tinyMCE is not defined,but adding the line scriptT.onload = function(){}

Now the error i come across is when i try to access this tinyMCE variable in my bookmarklet.js, its giving me an error tinyMCE null. Any ideas how to pass the tinyMCE variable from the main html page which has the bookmarklet function to the js file which processes what action when the bookmarklet is clicked?